# High uptake of memory in the nano process (root)

Tags: process

In `Ubuntu server 14.04` have a high consumption in the process called `nano` (root), which is consuming too much memory RAM. Why this happens? And as I controlled?, i have a server with 5 gb in ram and the process nano(root)consumer 2.5 gb.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please refrain from posting in ALL CAPS. Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/590206/edit) your question and correct it. Also add, why you think nano is using too much (how much is that?) RAM.

Answer (score 0):

nano is a small commandline text editor for Linux.

**Some possible explanations for the high memory consumption:**

- The application has been running a very long time with a memory leak
- The application has a VERY VERY big file open
- It's a virus concealing itself as nano

**What you can do to further investigate**

- `ps -auxuf` should give you a little bit more information, like what started the process and such.
- `which nano` gives the location of the file being run when `nano` is running. Check if this is `/usr/bin/nano` and if that really points to the nano text editor
- restart the server and see if the process comes back